# Lightbox for Bootstrap 5 not loading properly

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-lightbox

I'm having difficulties installing this Lightbox for Bootstrap 5 : https://trvswgnr.github.io/bs5-lightbox/

Even though it seems very easy to integrate and well documented, the pictures open in a new tab when clicked :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Lightbox for Bootstrap 5</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.8.3/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!--<script>
import Lightbox from 'bs5-lightbox';
document.querySelectorAll('.lightbox').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', Lightbox.initialize));    
</script>-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-3" data-code="example-1">
            <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=250" data-toggle="lightbox" data-caption="This describes the image">
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=250" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I read older questions on similar problems but they don't provide solution as they're not refering to the same plugins and BS versions.

Here are a few things I tried :

- I made sure the scripts were loading in the right order (and tried
  different positions)
- I double checked the URLs
- I litterally copied/pasted the example to avoid typo.
- I tried previous versions.
- I isolated all the scripts on a test page to avoid external conflict.
- I passed various options to check the reaction (the comments in the example below).
- I switched data-* attributes to data-bs-* (the new Bootstrap nomenclature)

My only doubt would be about PHP version on my server as I'm currently on PHP 7.0. What do you think ? Could it be the problem and how to be sure ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet you included in your post, you have the JavaScript in the header. If you put it at the end of the `body,` then the elements will exist for the JavaScript to act upon.

The source code you're using for bs5-lightbox includes the `querySelectorAll` function, so you don't need to include it again.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-code="example-1">
      <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=250" data-toggle="lightbox" data-caption="This describes the image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=250" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-code="example-2">
      <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=250" data-toggle="lightbox" data-caption="This describes the image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=250" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.8.3/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>
```